# Displaying all objects in json string

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to get all objects that are in a json string via `$.getJSON` and it works but I am having trouble showing them all (it only is showing the last object). I know its because its overwriting each entry via `.$each` but I've no clue on how to fix this, as I tried to append it but that just kept displaying each of the entries multiple times (I have it set to update every 5 seconds, to see if there are more entries available). Anyway, here is the code I have in place (both jQuery and PHP)

jQuery Code -

```
$(function() {
    function buildOnlineFriendList() {
        $.getJSON("/members/friends/get-friends-online")
        .done(function(msg) {
            if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(msg)) {
                $('#friends-online').html("No friends are online.");
            } else {
                $.each(msg, function(key, value) {
                    // how to display each friend online without overwriting each one to only display the last. :/
                    $('#friends-online').html("<a href=\"/members/chat/" + value.id + "\" class=\"chat-with\">" + value.name + "</a><br>");
                });
            }
        }).fail(function(msg) {
            $('#friends-online').html(msg.message);
        });
    }

    setInterval(function() {
         buildOnlineFriendList();
    }, 5000);

    buildOnlineFriendList();
});
```

PHP code -

```
public function getFriendsOnline()
{
    $query = $this->connection->execute("SELECT members.username AS friend_username, friends_online.user_id AS fo_id FROM friends_online, friends, members
        WHERE friends_online.user_id = friends.friend_id AND members.id = friends.friend_id AND friends.user_id = " . $this->getUserId()['id']);

    if ($query->count() > 0) {
        // get the id/username of the friend(s) online
        foreach ($query as $values) {
            $friends_online[] = array('id' => $values['fo_id'], 'name' => $values['friend_username']);
        }

        return $friends_online;
    } else {
        throw new FriendsException("No friends are online.");
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

(I can try and provide more information if my question is unclear)

Comment: I did that but it kept displaying everything all the time every 5 seconds, which is what I don't want..

Comment: Reset it every five seconds, using `$('#friends-online').empty()`, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know it's overwriting the values when writing using `$.each`.  The issue is it's writing the HTML for the `friends-online` element each loop.  All you need to do is to set this value in a variable and update the variable in each iteration. Then after the loop is done, set the HTML for the element.  I've modified your function to:

```
function buildOnlineFriendList() {
    $.getJSON("/members/friends/get-friends-online")
    .done(function(msg) {
        // create a variable to hold the html string
        var html = "";
        if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(msg)) {
            $('#friends-online').html("No friends are online.");
        } else {
            $.each(msg, function(key, value) {
                // set the value of the html here
                html += "<a href=\"/members/chat/" + value.id + "\" class=\"chat-with\">" + value.name + "</a><br>";
            });
            // set the html here, after the loop.
            $('#friends-online').html(html);                 
        }                       
    }).fail(function(msg) {
        $('#friends-online').html(msg.message);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#friends-online")
  .append(
      $("<a>")
        .attr("href", "/members/chat/" + value.id)
        .attr("class", "chat-with")
  )
  .append($("<br>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `$('#friends-online').html(...` with `$('#friends-online').append(...`. At the moment this line is resetting the HTML of #friends-online over and over, whereas using append will add each new user to the element.

You will need to also add `$('#friends-online').empty()` as the first line of your timer, i.e.

```
setInterval(function() {
     $('#friends-online').empty();
     buildOnlineFriendList();
}, 5000);
```

Or in the function itself, i.e.

```
function buildOnlineFriendList() {
    $('#friends-online').empty();
    $.getJSON("/members/friends/get-friends-online") ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replace this:

```
 $('#friends-online').html("<a href=\"/members/chat/" + value.id + "\" class=\"chat-with\">" + value.name + "</a><br>");
```

With this:

```
 $('#friends-online').append("<a href=\"/members/chat/" + value.id + "\" class=\"chat-with\">" + value.name + "</a><br>");
```

The .html() method will overwrite all existing HTML within the selected element.
The .append() method will add the content on to the end of the existing HTML